# Mysql if field null take some value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have such code:
(on RoR):

```
@types = Type.where("TYP_MOD_ID = ? AND (SUBSTRING(TYP_PCON_START,1,4) <= ?) AND (SUBSTRING(TYP_PCON_END,1,4) >= ?) AND TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID = ? ", params[:models], params[:year], params[:year], params[:fueltype]).order("TYP_HP_FROM")
```

But sometimes TYP_PCON_END is null in db.... How in such case use not null, but my value, sended by ruby (date.now(YEAR))?

**So how if field is null use another value?**
How to check on null, and use my code if not null `(SUBSTRING(TYP_PCON_END,1,4) >= ?)`
and another:

```
? >= ?
```

if null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE`:

```
SUBSTRING(COALESCE(TYP_PCON_END, 'some default string'),1,4) > ?
```

If you don't need the substring for your default value, then you would just do it this way:

```
COALESCE(SUBSTRING(TYP_PCON_END,1,4), 'AAAA') > ?
```

This works since doing a `SUBSTRING` on a null value will yield null as well.

Comment: but for my default value i don't need substring